# how to find replace value with whitespace using sed in a bash script

Tags: sed, replace

I have values in a file like this **' value-to-remove '**(without the ' characters). I want to use sed to run through the file and replace the values **including the space** before and after. I am running this via a bash script.
How can I do this?

The sed command I'm using at the moment replaces the values but leaves behind the two spaces.

```
sed -i 's/ '$value' / /g' test.conf
```

---

In script I have

```
sed -i -e 's/\s'$DOMAIN'-'$SITE'\s/\s/g' gitosis.conf
```

echoed as

```
sed -i -e s/\sffff.com-eeee\s/\s/g test.conf
```

Not working though.

Comment: btw, you should show your input and the wanted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO your sed does not know '\s', so use `[ \t]`, and use double quotes, otherwise your variables will not expand. e.g.:

```
sed -i -e "s/[ \t]'$DOMAIN'-'$SITE'[ \t]/ /g" gitosis.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you need

```
echo 'Some values to remove value-to-remove and more' | sed -e 's/\svalue-to-remove\s/CHANGED/g'
```

output: `Some values to removeCHANGEDand more`